# Dual of a smooth hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it true that the dual of a smooth hypersurface $X$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $d\ge 2$ is a hypersurface? If yes, could you give me a simple proof ? Or a reference?

Note that in this case, the dual is birational to $X$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the dual is a hypersurface.  Here is a simple proof when $n\geq 4$.  First of all, by the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, the restriction homomorphism, $$ r : \text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^n) \to \text{Pic}(X),$$ is an isomorphism.  In particular, every invertible sheaf on $X$ is either ample, trivial, or anti-ample.

Denote the Gauss map on $X$ by, $$ G : X \to (\mathbb{P}^n)^\vee, \ \ x \mapsto \mathbb{T}_xX, $$   where $\mathbb{T}_x X$ denotes the tangent hyperplane to $X$ at $x$.
The invertible sheaf $G^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is either ample, trivial or anti-ample.  If $G$ is nonconstant, then $G^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ has positive degree Hilbert polynomial, hence $G^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is neither trivial nor anti-ample.  Therefore $G^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is ample.  In particular, $G$ can have no positive dimensional fiber, since this would give a subvariety of $X$ on which $G^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is not ample.  Therefore $G$ is finite, and hence $\text{dim}(G(X))$ equals $\text{dim}(X)$.

Finally, if $G$ were constant with image $[H]$, for $H$ a fixed hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$, then for every $x\in X$, the tangent hyperplane to $\mathbb{T}_x X$ equals $H$.  In particular, for every $x\in X$, $x$ is contained in $H$.  Thus $X$ is contained in $H$, contradicting that $X$ is a smooth hypersurface of degree $d>1$.

**Edit.** I just want to add, I heard this argument long ago, but I do not know who first proved this result.  Fyodor Zak has done important work on the Gauss map, so you might consult his work to try and find a reference.

**Second edit.** The OP asks about $n=3$.  One could probably adapt the "fast" argument above using Noether-Lefschetz, but it is probably more honest just to compute $G^*\mathcal{O}(1)$.  Indeed, the morphism $G$ arises from the short exact sequence sequence,
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-d)|_X \xrightarrow{u} \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n/k}|_X \to \Omega_{X/k} \to 0,$$
and the Euler sequence (restricted to $X$),
$$ 0 \to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n/k}|_X \xrightarrow{v} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)^{\oplus(n+1)}|_X \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}|_X \to 0. $$
The adjoint of $v\circ u$ is an invertible quotient,
$$ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus(n+1)}|_X \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)|_X, $$
which is equivalent to an invertible quotient (after twisting),
$$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}^{\oplus(n+1)}|_X \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d-1)|_X. $$
This invertible quotient defines the morphism $G:X\to (\mathbb{P}^n)^\vee$.  Thus, $G^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d-1)|_X$.  Thus, if $d>1$, then $G^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is ample.  Hence $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 5):

A reference for this statement is Dolgachev's beautiful book *Classical Algebraic Geometry*, Chapter 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but where exactly? Actually, I had already read this chapter partially just before asking the question, but probably not the right result.

Comment: In the file of the book I have, it is explained in Section 1.2.2, soon after the Reflexivity Theorem.

Comment: What I had read is "Let us apply this to the case when X is a nonsingular hypersurface. The polar map is a finite map, hence the dual of a nonsingular hypersurface is a
hypersurface." and it is true that this is quite easy, but I wanted the argument (given by Jason Starr above). Thanks to both of you for your help.